# socket.getaddrinfo doesn't return my IPV6 address with AF_INET6 or "0" as arguments

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, ipv6, getaddrinfo

I'm using the following Python code to fetch ipv4 and ipv6 addresses information (according to millions of tutorials i went through including https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html), but i receive only the ipv4 info. My ipv6 connection is ok, i can see my addresses via "ipconfig /all", the host i'm trying to connect to is "akamai.com" (also tried www.python.org and example.org).
I have also tried the 0 argument (full range of results) instead of limiting it to socket.AF_INET6 or socket.AF_INET and yet i receive only the ipv4 address

```
import sys, socket

x = socket.getaddrinfo("akamai.com", 80, socket.AF_INET6, 0, socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.AI_CANONNAME)

#Expected format (as i found in some examples in this site):

socket.getaddrinfo("www.python.org", 80, 0, 0, socket.SOL_TCP)
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('82.94.164.162', 80)),
(10, 1, 6, '', ('2001:888:2000:d::a2', 80, 0, 0))]
```

I receive only the first tulip (plus the canonical name)

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't reproduce your problem.

`socket.getaddrinfo("akamai.com", 80, socket.AF_INET6, 0, socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.AI_CANONNAME)` which returns
`[(30, 1, 6, 'akamai.com', ('2a02:26f0:ee:18f::22df', 80, 0, 0)),
 (30, 1, 6, 'akamai.com', ('2a02:26f0:ee:1a4::22df', 80, 0, 0))]`

The answers seem to be fine.

Comment: Thanks for trying! (i'm actually glad it worked for you) I'll update the post <when> i have further insights.

Comment: It works for me too. Are you sure you actually have _global_ IPv6 connectivity?

Comment: Having connectivity or not shouldn't influence DNS lookups though...